# Is there a word for "to make parallel'?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose I want to say something like

> "The author **draws a parallel between** the spider and the man by doing this...".

Is there a word I can use in place of "draws a parallel between"?

Comment: Try "...author **compares** the spider **to** the man by...". More context would be nice.

Comment: **Parallel** can also be a verb: *"the increase in the quality of wines has paralleled the rise of interest in food"*

Comment: Well, there's "parallelize", but I've only seen it in the sense of making two things parallel.

Comment: @NVZ But in this example *draws a parallel* is being used in the sense of making a comparison 9as someone else has pointed out). I have never seen the verb *parallel* used in that sense.

Comment: @WS2 Actually I pointed that out. My first comment asked for more context. :)

Comment: To _make parallel_ is not the same as _to draw [point out] a parallel between_.

Comment: @HotLicks : ​ I was thinking of that word too, but _I've_ "only seen it in the sense of" [computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @HotLicks: Agreed with Ricky on this one.  I wouldn't describe rotating a line segment to make it parallel with another line segment as parallelizing them.  I'd only use it to describe turning a serial algorithm / program into a multithreaded one, or to expose parallelism that allows SIMD vectorization or even just instruction-level parallelism for superscalar CPUs.

Comment: @PeterCordes -- [The two cases are not parallel.  Men should not parallelize and confound two things, ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=R-hiAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA105&dq=%22parallelize%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRlciXu-HLAhXDnYMKHQnKBwwQ6AEIQjAH#v=onepage&q=%22parallelize%22&f=false), Blaise Pascal, translated 1825.  (And I don't think he was talking about the Pascal programming language.)

Answer (score 11):

To *[draw a parallel](http://www.sky-net-eye.com/eng/english/idioms/american/i_d/1939-draw-a-parallel)*  basically means to **compare**. Other words that can work include **relate** and **connect**. In your context, the author is drawing a relationship or a connection between the spider and the man.

> (As defined on dictionary.com)
>
> **[compare](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/compare?s=t)** - to consider or describe as similar
>
> **[relate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/relate)** - to bring into or establish association, connection, or relation
>
> **[connect](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/connect?s=ts)** - to relate or associate

Answer (score 7):

I tend to prefer this verb for this sort of analogy:

> [***liken***](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/liken) - consider or describe as similar, equal, or analogous

Though it's not a pure fill-in given the question here.   You would generally not use *liken* with "the" articles attached to both "spider" and "man."

"The author likened the spider to a man," is perfectly acceptable though. Or, if a specific man is being described as spiderlike, the other way around: "the author likened the man to a spider."

Answer (score 4):

"Compare" is a good replacement.  You could also use:

To draw/make/suggest an [**analogy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analogy)

Source: Merriam Webster

1
:  inference that if two or more things agree with one another in some respects they will probably agree in others

2
a :  resemblance in some particulars between things otherwise unlike :  similarity

b :  comparison based on such resemblance

3
:  correspondence between the members of pairs or sets of linguistic forms that serves as a basis for the creation of another form

...

The verb "analogize" exists, but is a bit awkward.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that "equate" would be a good replacement for your example.

> "The author **equates** the spider with the man by doing this..."

From [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equate):

**Equate**: to treat, represent, or regard as equal, equivalent, or comparable.

---

If you are looking for a looser connection than equality between the two objects (in your case, the spider and the man), I would prefer, as @Jon already noted, the word "relates":

> "The author **relates** the spider and the man by doing this..."

From [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relate):

**Relate**: to show or establish logical or causal connection between.

Answer (score 2):

**Parallelize**

Used in [an 1825 translation](https://books.google.com/books?id=R-hiAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA105&dq=%22parallelize%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRlciXu-HLAhXDnYMKHQnKBwwQ6AEIQjAH#v=onepage&q=%22parallelize%22&f=false) of a book by Blaise Pascal.

Context:

> It is very unjust, therefore, to pretend that theirs are as well sustained as ours, when they have no figures of established interpretation to refer to as we have.  The two cases are not parallel.  Men should not **parallelize** and confound two things, because in one respect they appear similar, seeing that in another, they are so different.

Comment: +1 Nice find, but isn't **parallelize** used in *computing* mostly? Would it be understood if used outside of *computing*?

Comment: @NVZ - You're saying that a person of average intelligence can't figure out the meaning of "parallelize" even if they've never heard it before??

Comment: @NVZ - And I saw dozens of other references -- the above is just one of the oldest that isn't used too obscurely to serve as a decent example.

Answer (score 1):

Two unorthodox thoughts:

- The author *connects* the situation of spider and man.
- The author *maps* the situation of spider to the situation of man.

Comment: _Mapping/connecting_ is much stronger than making a parallelism, i.e. a comparison, however.

Comment: @black: I myself don't feel that this is *the* answer OP is looking for. These are just some suggestions which may be useful for people reading the answers who have a question similar to this one.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the provided answers are sound.
 You may also consider verbs such as ***juxtapose/s*** (to place side by side), ***juxtaposit/s*** (to place in close connection), and ***identify/ies*** (consider to be equal or the same [especially in relation to people or archetypes]).